# Image in TableviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, plist

I want to create `TableViewCell` with image. Image values from my plist. Which method needed? How do it?
It is code by which i want to add image in `tableviewcell`

```
    NSArray *brend =[brends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *logo = [[brend objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Image"];

    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:logo];
```

My plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>Mercedec</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>Mercedes.png</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Rena</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>Renault.png</string>
    </dict>
```

**But it crashed**

Since recently started to learn `Objective-C`. can anyone help me out here?

**EDIT:**

```
@interface MainTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *companylist;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *brends;

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

@synthesize brends,companylist;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    NSString *Stplist= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wunder" ofType:@"plist"];


    companylist = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:Stplist];
    self.brends = [[self.companylist allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return brends.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    cell.textLabel.text=brends[indexPath.row];


    NSArray *imagesArray= [companylist allValues ];


    NSString *logo= [[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Image"];

    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:logo];


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: can post the crash log? and what is brends? is it an array or dictionary based on your plist it supposed to be a dictionary

Comment: I guess brend is 'brand' - as in brand of car.

Comment: You get this image from Json?Are you really want to make it store in Plist?

Comment: It is in dictionary so you have get those images in Dictionary and then use object for key. please post your entire code in cell for rowatindexpath to get it done

Comment: I added TableviewController.m. in my question Please check @Arun

Comment: It is dictionary @Joshua

Answer (score 1):

use this code

NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary       dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my" ofType:@"plist"]];

```
NSArray *imagesArray= [picturesDictionary allValues];
```

in table view methods use this

```
NSString *yourPicName= [[imagesArray objectAtIndex:index.row]valueForKey:@"Image"];
```

Comment: NSDictionary is an unordered collection. To say "the order I added them" has no meaning.

If you want to access the keys in a certain order then you'll either have to store an array along side your dictionary or get the keys and then sort them and use that to access the values in that order.

Comment: Root ---- Dictionary
       PhotosArray ----- Array 
             Item 0   ------ String --  image.jpg

Comment: NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Photos" ofType:@"plist"]];     
   NSArray *imageArray = [picturesDictionary    objectForKey:@"PhotosArray"]; 
PhotosInAlbum.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own cell (New File --> Cocoa class with xib which is subclass to UITableViewCell). There you can add whatyou want and where you want (Image View, more Labels)

Comment: I don't need a separate cell. The problem is that I can not take image data from the plist